# XML database eXist and grammar validation

Tags: java, xml, xsd, catalog, exist-db

here I am again :/
I managed to make exist database run in embedded mode. However, what I can't make work is implicit XML validation.
I proceeded according to this page: http://exist.sourceforge.net/validation.html

This is my conf.xml:

```
<validation mode="auto">
    <entity-resolver>
    <catalog uri="/db/catalog.xml" />
    </entity-resolver>
</validation>
```

This is my catalog.xml which I inserted into exist database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
         "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">

    <uri name="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" uri="videodes.xsd"/>
</catalog>
```

My XML schema videodes.xsd which I also inserted into database looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    ...
</xsd:schema>
```

(I think the entire content of this file isn't important, it would just make this question too long)

And this is my file (videodes.xml) which I inserted into the database and which I want to have validated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<videodes xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="videodes.xsd" xmlns=""
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ...
</videodes>
```

(again I don't think it's necessary to put here the entire content)

Unfortunately, validation doesn't work and I can insert invalid data into my videodes.xml. 
What Am I missing ? I guess my catalog.xml is the problem, but I don't know what I should put in it. I tried to search a lot but it wasn't any use.

I will appreciate any help because I really need to make this work.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9122035/230955), which *may* be of some help. In brief, if your application lives in a closed intranet, the presence of the DOCTYPE declaration on your catalog.xml file might be the problem, as its system identifier won't be able to resolve. The DOCTYPE declaration is not necessary (except to validate the file) so remove it when in production.